# Use Calendar function for leap year

Tags: python, python-import, leap-year

I'm trying to use the import function to calculate my leap year, however I've been getting error messages for my code:

```
import calendar
year=input("Enter a year: ")
check=calendar.isleap(year)
if check == True:
    print("In",year,"February has 29 days.")
else:
    print("In",year,"February has 28 days.")
```

Would appreciate it if anyone can point out my mistake here!

I've also tried the

```
return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)
```

method by using 'if-else' statements, but have also seem to stumble onto a roadblock using that method as well...My code for that method is shown below:

```
print ('hi')
input_year= input("Please enter a year: ")
if (input_year) % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0):
    print ("Yes sir")
else:
    print ("no sir")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2 will automatically attempt to convert the **string** the user typed into a number and return an int from the `input` function if it can.  But Python 3 will be more consistent and always return a **string** even if the characters the user typed are logically understood to be a number.

Hence, do this:

```
import calendar
year=input("Enter a year: ")
year = int(year)
check=calendar.isleap(year)
if check:
    print("In",year,"February has 29 days.")
else:
    print("In",year,"February has 28 days.")
```

Comment: Great thank you! Just wanted to clarify -- is it by design that you typed "if check:" instead of "if check==True"?

Comment: Yes.  But that's a style difference, not a bug in your code per se.

Comment: Also, if you found this answer useful, don't forget to upvote it and/or accept it.